# What blocks can Mobs/The Player spawn on?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was wondering what specific blocks a mob can spawn on, and which ones they can't. I know that block "opacity" and "transparency" have a part to play, but not all of these rules apply properly.

Can someone generate a list of all the blocks a mob (and if there is a difference between hostile/passive mob) can spawn on?

Is there any restriction for a player?

Comment: "the block directly below it must have a solid top surface (opaque, upside down slabs / stairs and others)" talk about a useless wiki article... What "others"?

Comment: For mobs, you can install client mod NotEnoughItems (NEI), then pressing F7 can highlight all actually possible spawn blocks for hostile mobs. Yellow crosses mean that mobs can spawn in night, red crosses that they can spawn even in a day. If the block is not capable of spawning a mob, there will be no cross (no matter if there is a lot of  light or block type blocks the spawning) - this can help you to actually SEE this whole thing in practical manner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A player can spawn on any solid block which is not affected by gravity and is below the sky, so there are no blocks above it.

Animals spawn on grass or dirt exclusively (block id 2 and 3). They also require a light level above 9 and at least 2 blocks of air above them. Exception is the bat, which spawns on opaque blocks if the light level is below 9.

Skeletons, Zombies, and Creepers can spawn on any opaque block if the light level is below 7. Exception are mobs in the nether, which can spawn on netherrack, no matter what the light level is.

Opaque blocks include:

```
1      --> Stone
1:1    --> Granite
1:2    --> Polished Granite
1:3    --> Diorite
1:4    --> Polished Diorite
1:5    --> Andesite
1:6    --> Polished Andesite
2      --> Grass
3      --> Dirt
3:1    --> Coarse Dirt
3:2    --> Podzol
4      --> Cobblestone
5      --> Oak Wood Plank
5:1    --> Spruce Wood Plank
5:2    --> Birch Wood Plank
5:3    --> Jungle Wood Plank
5:4    --> Acacia Wood Plank
5:5    --> Dark Oak Wood Plank
12     --> Sand
12:1   --> Red Sand
13     --> Gravel
14     --> Gold Ore
15     --> Iron Ore
16     --> Coal Ore
17     --> Oak Wood
17:1   --> Spruce Wood
17:2   --> Birch Wood
17:3   --> Jungle Wood
35     --> White Wool
35:1   --> Orange Wool
35:2   --> Magenta Wool
35:3   --> Light Blue Wool
35:4   --> Yellow Wool
35:5   --> Lime Wool
35:6   --> Pink Wool
35:7   --> Gray Wool
35:8   --> Light Gray Wool
35:9   --> Cyan Wool
35:10  --> Purple Wool
35:11  --> Blue Wool
35:12  --> Brown Wool
35:13  --> Green Wool
35:14  --> Red Wool
35:15  --> Black Wool
41     --> Gold Block
42     --> Iron Block
43     --> Double Stone Slab
43:1   --> Double Sandstone Slab
43:2   --> Double Wooden Slab
43:3   --> Double Cobblestone Slab
43:4   --> Double Brick Slab
43:5   --> Double Stone Brick Slab
43:6   --> Double Nether Brick Slab
43:7   --> Double Quartz Slab
45     --> Bricks
47     --> Bookshelf
48     --> Moss Stone
49     --> Obsidian
56     --> Diamond Ore
57     --> Diamond Block
78     --> Snow
80     --> Snow Block
87     --> Netherrack
97     --> Stone Monster Egg
97:1   --> Cobblestone Monster Egg
97:2   --> Stone Brick Monster Egg
97:3   --> Mossy Stone Brick Monster Egg
97:4   --> Cracked Stone Brick Monster Egg
97:5   --> Chiseled Stone Brick Monster Egg
98     --> Stone Bricks
98:1   --> Mossy Stone Bricks
98:2   --> Cracked Stone Bricks
98:3   --> Chiseled Stone Bricks
99     --> Brown Mushroom Block
100    --> Red Mushroom Block
159    --> White Stained Clay
159:1  --> Orange Stained Clay
159:2  --> Magenta Stained Clay
159:3  --> Light Blue Stained Clay
159:4  --> Yellow Stained Clay
159:5  --> Lime Stained Clay
159:6  --> Pink Stained Clay
159:7  --> Gray Stained Clay
159:8  --> Light Gray Stained Clay
159:9  --> Cyan Stained Clay
159:10 --> Purple Stained Clay
159:11 --> Blue Stained Clay
159:12 --> Brown Stained Clay
159:13 --> Green Stained Clay
159:14 --> Red Stained Clay
159:15 --> Black Stained Clay
179    --> Red Sandstone
179:1  --> Smooth Red Sandstone
179:2  --> Chiseled Red Sandstone
```

I hope I didn't forget any, if I did, feel free to add them.

Comment: Can regular mobs spawn on netherrack? And are you saying that (Pigzombies for example) can *only*spawn on netherrack?

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to list transparent blocks? That's a smaller list. Glass, glowstone, bottom slabs

Comment: @Ben No. Regular mobs can't spawn on netherrack. The only exception are skeletons which can spawn - only in the nether - on netherbrick. And yes, all mobs which appear only in the nether can only spawn there, even if you place netherrack in the overworld, there won't spawn any mobs on it. The only exception are zombie pigmen, but it's not really an exception, they can walk through the portal and appear in the overworld. They don't really spawn there.

Comment: @Unionhawk Probably, but it's easier to pick them from this list instead of looking if the block is not in this list.^^

Comment: @YUNOWORK I am almost certain this isn't correct, but I'll do some testing later before I authoritatively call you wrong.

Comment: @Unionhawk If I'm wrong, feel free to correct me. But i used a lot of netherrack in the overworld to raise nether warts and I've never encountered a random magma slime jumping into my face.

Comment: This is currently wrong. Mobs can definitely spawn on some of the non-opaque blocks, namely top half-slabs and upside-down stairs. Ocelots can spawn on leaves. Furthermore, Bedrock is opaque and does not support mobs spawning.

Comment: @MrLemon The player can spawn on leaves too, i completely forgot about that one. I didn't include Bedrock in the list because I knew that there can nothing spawn on that. But I'm pretty sure that spawning on half-slabs or stairs isn't possible. Guess I'll try that once I'm home.

Comment: Following all this testing what did people discover?

Answer (score 6):

All transparent blocks, with the exception of slime blocks, redstone blocks, and active redstone ore (when glowing after being hit), *cannot* be spawned upon.

A full list of the transparent blocks that no monsters spawn on:

```
Furnace (when active) 
Glass 
Glowstone 
Ice 
Jack o'Lantern 
Leaves (Fancy graphics) 
Piston (Retracted) 
Redstone Lamp (when active) 
Redstone Ore (when active) 
Sticky Piston (Retracted) 
TNT
Anvil
Bed 
Brewing Stand 
Cake 
Carpet 
Cauldron 
Chest 
Cobblestone Wall 
Daylight Sensor 
Door 
Enchantment Table 
Ender Chest 
Farmland 
Fence 
Fence Gate 
Glass Pane 
Iron Bars 
Ladder 
Lily Pad 
Nether Brick Fence 
Piston (Extended) 
Redstone Repeater 
Redstone Comparator 
Snow (layer) (2 - 8 layers) 
Sticky Piston (Extended) 
Trapdoor 
Trapped Chest 
Vines
Button 
Lever 
Pressure Plate 
Weighted Pressure Plate 
Rail 
Powered Rail 
Detector Rail 
Activator Rail 
Redstone Dust 
Redstone Torch
Air 
End Portal 
Fire 
Portal 
Sign 
Snow (cover) (single layer) 
Torch
Cactus 
Crops 
Flowers 
Grass 
Mushrooms 
Saplings  
Sugar Cane
Lava 
Water
End Portal Frame 
Mob Spawner
```

Exceptions that are both transparent and spawnable upon:

```
Block of Redstone
Hopper
Slime
```

Also other notable exceptions:

Slabs not aligned with the top of the block-space (normal) cannot be a spawning are. Slabs aligned with the top/double slabs can be spawned upon.

Right-side-up stairs (stair side up) cannot be spawned upon, upside down one can (flat side up).

Comment: In the previous answer one of he comments mentioned that you (the player) are able to spawn on leaves, as well as mobs such as pigs or cows etc. I don't remember seeing any situations where hostile mobs can spawn on leaves, so can you clarify that for me?

Comment: @Ben I'm not sure about that. Maybe leaves are another exception? I haven't seen hostile _or_ peaceful mobs spawn on leaves though.

Comment: Just to mention - this was in an earlier version that I found this, and I can't remember if it was "fancy graphics" or not (honestly I haven't played properly since 1.8). So if you could verify this, that would just about sum it up :)

Answer (score 2):

Been testing on creative, MC 1.10.

Tested the tranparent blocks list above and so far Jack-o-lanterns will spawn mobs. AFAIK, Jack-o's aren't transparent anyhow. They just behave differently. They also emit a light level of 14 (?) so in the overworld, hostiles wont spawn?

Add to lists of spawnable blocks: Pistons (sticky or otherwise, retracted or extended), and string

Spawn through blocks (mobs don't spawn on them but they can spawn through them, i.e. on the block said block is on.): Signs, Torches

(Test are in nether, above bedrock, at highest level, or at least 2 blocks below that coz there's no light in 256)