# Will this spawn slimes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to build a slime spawning platform. Currently, my plan is to make a big platform, and then use iron golems and myself (in fences) to lure slimes towards them. When they get close enough they'll die due to magma blocks.

I'm not getting any slimes to spawn yet, even though according to the wiki I've done all that I need to do: [Minecraft Wiki (Slimes)](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Slime). The moon on the night that I build this was not a full moon, but I expect that I should have gotten some. Can anyone help?

**Stats:**

- y=65
- Swampland biome
- Fences are placed every 15 blocks
- There is no light source on the platform

**Here's a picture of it:**

[image: Slime Spawning Platform]

**Thanks for your help!**

Comment: Just to clarify, make sure you *are* in the swampland biome. From this image it looks like you have simply built this over the water, and the biome can change when you go too far out. Also, check [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/220224/what-blocks-can-mobs-the-player-spawn-on) about suitable spawning platform materials.

Comment: Also, mobs only spawn within a certain distance of the player. Mobs spawn when you are at least 24 blocks away, but then despawn over time when they are 32 blocks or more away.

Comment: @Ben  I am in the swampland; I just checked. I'll try standing at one end to see if they spawn. Thanks!

Comment: @Ben I have tried being close enough and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I actually found that there were slimes spawning on it today; I guess that they just aren't frequent enough for me to notice it before now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks correct as far as I can tell. Here's some more things to consider though:

- Are you far enough away? Mobs (including slimes) will not spawn within 24 blocks of you (unless they came from a mob spawner block - yours didn't).
- Are you close enough? Mobs (including slimes) will not spawn unless as the chunk is loaded and you are closer than 128 blocks (IIRC. It might be another large number).
- Are the slimes despawning? When you get far enough from mobs, I think 32 blocks, they may despawn after some time passes. Keep an eye out for slimes spawning then despawning, don't just AFK and expect to come back to a platform full of slimes.
- Are the slimes spawning somewhere else, other than the platform? In a cave, for example. It could happen, but unlikely.
- Has the mob cap been reached? After a certain number of mobs spawn, to prevent lag the game will not spawn any more until some are killed or despawn.
- Is it really a swamp biome? Hit F3 to check. On a laptop, you may need to press Fn-F3.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I actually found that there were slimes spawning on it today; I guess that they just aren't frequent enough for me to notice it before now. Thanks!