# Can Endermen spawn on smooth stone?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have been 30 block away on my farm in Minecraft Bedrock because my simulation distance is in 4, I did that because the tutorial said so, but he said I can use any solid block for Enderman to spawn, so I used smooth stone (because it looked kinds cool) and they don't spawn in, I tried replacing it with the end block, and worked.

Is this a bug?

Comment: That makes sense, so I'd say yes.
Slabs are spawnproof, but not smooth stone, just their slabs.

Comment: [Related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/220224/what-blocks-can-mobs-the-player-spawn-on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [Enderman](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enderman#Spawning) can spawn on any solid surface that has at least three empty spaces above at light level 7 or less. They are the only mob that spawns in all 3 dimensions.

Just like all other mobs, Endermen need to spawn on a solid, opaque block. You can pave an area with half-slabs, stairs, or glass, among other things, to prevent them from spawning there.

[Here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Spawn-proofing) is a list of spawnproof blocks, and *Smooth Stone* is not listed.

Comment: A small observation: _bottom_ half-slabs are spawn proof, but _top_ half-slabs are able to spawn mobs just like any regular block.